# Tilde expansion vs. variables in Bash

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables, tilde

Please, consider the following snippet:

```
$ export xx=foo
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $xx ~'
/root
```

Which is ok. We can't see xx.

However, if I expose it:

```
$ sudo -E bash -c 'echo $xx ~'
foo /home/xropi
```

Though many say *~* is not alias, somehow it's part of the environment because *-E* will expose the original preventing me to defer its evaluation.

Is it possible to pass my variables and evaluate ~ as /root in the sudo-ed command?

I'd like to get this when running with sudo:

```
foo /root
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your understanding of how tilde works is incomplete.  See `man bash` and search for `Tilde Expansion`.

It begins with (extra newlines and some bolding added by me):

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~`), all of the
> characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there is
> no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.
>
> If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in
> the tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login name.
>
> If this login name is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the value
> of the shell parameter `HOME`.  **If `HOME` is unset**, the home directory of
> the user executing the shell is substituted instead.
>
> Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory associated
> with the specified login name.

In short, `~` expands to $HOME, if $HOME is non-empty.

`sudo` does not preserve the user's environment variables (including `$HOME`) when run without `-E`.  With `-E`, it does.

BTW, also worth noting: while most shells can and do expand `~` to mean the user's home directory, not all programs do.  In fact, most programs don't - it's not really their job to do that, they rely on the shell to perform tilde and variable and glob and other expansions **before** they see any arguments.

---

**Question: is it possible to pass my variables and evaluate ~ as /root in the sudo-ed command?**

There are several ways, each with advantages and disadvantages.  Here are some of them:

1. `unset HOME` before running `sudo -E`.
2. set `HOME=/root` before running `sudo -E`. e.g. `HOME=/root sudo -E bash -c 'echo $xx ~'`
3. Write the variables that you want to share with sudo to a file.  e.g. you could run `declare -p var1 var2 var3 > /tmp/myvars.sh` and have `sudo` (without `-E`) run a shell script that does `source /tmp/myvars.sh` before running whatever it is that you want to run with `sudo`.
4. Use the `env_keep` setting in `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/sudoers.d/*` - this allows you to define which variables will always be preserved when running `sudo`, with or without the `-E` option.
5. (from @MichaelHomer)  Use `sudo`'s `-H` option to set HOME to the **target user**'s home dir and `--preserve-env=xx` to tell sudo to pass on the `xx` variable (this option takes a comma-separated list of environment variable names).   See `man sudo` for details.  Note that not all users have permission to preserve the environment.  See `man sudoers`.

Note that there are good reasons why `sudo` does not preserve env vars by default.  There are many env vars that have serious security implications, and that misuse may allow users or groups to gain root (or other uid) access to things they should not have access to.

Comment: Upvoted for "sudo does not preserve the user's environment variables (including $HOME) when run without -E. With -E, it does.". It saved me day.